# make install -j8: ldconfig fails to run in parallel

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing, installation, ld

I have a library which I compile with `make` and install with `make install`.

It has several modules which can be installed separately with something like `make install_foo`, and `make install` is just a wrapper that has all of them as requirements.

Every module (`install_foo`, `install_bar`, ...) runs `$(MAKE) conf_ld` as its last command:

```
.PHONY: conf_ld
conf_ld:
    @echo   "   LDCONFIG"
    $(Q)cp -r -f $(v)   $(ETC_DIR)/ld.so.conf.d/*       \
                    $(DESTDIR)/etc/ld.so.conf.d/
    $(Q)ldconfig
    @echo
```

The problem is that if you try to install with multiple cores (`-j 8` for example), `ldconfig` runs in parallel and fails:

```
    LDCONFIG
    LDCONFIG
    LDCONFIG
ldconfig: ldconfig: Renaming of /etc/ld.so.cache~ to /etc/ld.so.cache failedRenaming of /etc/ld.so.cache~ to /etc/ld.so.cache failed: No such file or directory: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to solve this, or is it impossible to install in parallel?

Comment: If you must run the command as a sub-make then there's no good way to avoid this.  Every sub-make has its own dependency graph and they cannot coordinate which targets are being built in parallel, only _how many_ targets are being built.  Only if you can run all the targets within a single instance of make, can it work so that the command is only invoked one time.

Comment: @MadScientist But is there a way to do that without sub-make?  It's a post, not a prerequisite, so AFAIK, I know no other way to do so.  My problem is that I want to be able to run each target separately or all together, so I need to be able to run ldconfig in both cases.  The only way I found to do that is a sub-make for every individual target (running ldconfig twice isn't a problem).

Comment: I hesitate to suggest a 'kludge' but... would using [`flock`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/flock.1.html) be permissible here to force the `ldconfig` invocations to be sequential?

Comment: @G.M.  It is a solution; very clever!